# How can i use key and keyref on type xsd:list on xsd file?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

How can i use key and keyref when attribute type = list ?

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SuperClass">
  <xsd:list itemType="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:key name="GlobalClassNameKey">
  <xsd:selector xpath=".//ns:Class"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@Name"/>
</xsd:key>    

<xsd:keyref name="ClassSuperClassKeyRef" refer="ns:GlobalClassNameKey">
   <xsd:selector xpath=".//ns:Class"/>
   <xsd:field xpath="@SuperClass"/>
</xsd:keyref>
```

when i used this code its fail its only answer one string not string-list.We can use key and keyref on type list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You would have to change from attribute to a repeating element, using an atomic type.